# PHP socket check if not connecting

Tags: php, sockets

```
$socket = stream_socket_client('udp://'.$_GET["ip"].':'.$_GET["port"]);
if (!$socket) {
    die("not ok");
}
```

In my mind, this would check if it's possible to connect, and if not; die with message "not ok". But this only gives me error 500, and when I turn on reporting it says more in depth why, such as it couldn't connect to socket.

Why will this not die, but give error 500? Is there any way for me to know if my socket connects, before it kills the site?

Edit: my GET's are set with ip and port

I can connect when IP is correct

Comment: you need also to test the $_GET values if they are set or not

Comment: They're set, ip and port!

Comment: `Warning
UDP sockets will sometimes appear to have opened without an error, even if the remote host is unreachable. The error will only become apparent when you read or write data to/from the socket. The reason for this is because UDP is a "connectionless" protocol, which means that the operating system does not try to establish a link for the socket until it actually needs to send or receive data.`

Comment: ^^ from the manual

Comment: @prodigitalson but it does try to connect, since it returns error 500?

Answer (score 0):

UDP itself is a non reliable transport protocol.

You will **never** be able to check whether or not there is a problem, even when you actually send the Datagram from the socket.

So, relying on this hypothesis, just follow the socket API specs and send your message. If the message gets received ok, nothing you can do otherwise.

If you’re not ok with it, consider passing to TCP sockets.

Comment: Thanks. But when I try to post and the UDP fails, it'll not even try to send but give me error 500?

Comment: Are you sure it’s a problem of the socket? Maybe the error is triggered by something else. Also because it doesn’t die (actually the socket is non-null).

Comment: Nope. The udp socket can’t give error. Because he can’t know whether it can connect to the other point or not. Your problem is elsewhere.